# Taking input from tkinter.Text and printing the results

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

I've been working on a GUI program to sanitise URLs and IP addresses. Currently the **"Print"** button which I want to sanitise input and print results, is not working. My other functions work how I want them to, which have been tested.

In the **printOut()** function, that code snippet worked in a previous CLI version I was working on.

I've included a screenshot of my GUI interface to show what I want results to look like. Any help on my code would be greatly appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog

# help information -- works
def help_info():
    h = messagebox.showinfo("Help", "This program is used to defang/sanitise URLs and IP addresses.\n"
                                    "\nEnter a URL or IP address into the top input field and have it printed to the 'Results' output or, save it to a file.")

# Print sanitised results out
# not working
def printOut():
    url = inputTextbox.get(1.0, "end-1c")

    if "http" in url:
        url = url.replace("http", "hxxp")
        url = url.replace(":", "[:]")
        url = url.replace(".", "[.]")

    elif "https" in url:
        url = url.replace("https", "hxxps")
        url = url.replace(":", "[:]")
        url = url.replace(".", "[.]")

    elif "http" not in url:
        url = url.replace(".", "[.]")

    elif "https" not in url:
        url = url.replace(".", "[.]")
    return(url)

# save output to a file -- works
def save_as():
    save_output = filedialog.asksaveasfile()


# quit the program -- works
def quit_program():
    are_you_sure = messagebox.askquestion("Quit", "Are you sure?")
    if are_you_sure == 'yes':
        mainWindow.destroy()
    else:
        mainWindow.mainloop()


# Create mainWindow, not resizeable
mainWindow = tk.Tk()
mainWindow.title("Defang")
mainWindow.geometry("585x355-730-400")
mainWindow.resizable(False, False)

# label for user input
input_label = tk.Label(mainWindow, text="Enter URL(s) and or IP Address(s)", font="Arial 9")
input_label.place(x=7, y=5)

# input textbox
inputTextbox = tk.Text(mainWindow, width=70, height=8)
inputTextbox.place(x=10, y=25)

# label for output
output_label = tk.Label(mainWindow, text="Results", font="Arial 9")
output_label.place(x=7, y=165)

# results textbox
outputTextbox = tk.Text(mainWindow, width=70, height=8)
outputTextbox.place(x=10, y=185)

# help button
help_button = tk.Button(mainWindow, text="Help", padx=20, pady=0, command=help_info)
help_button.place(x=100, y=325)

# print button
print_button = tk.Button(mainWindow, text="Print", padx=20, pady=0, command=printOut)
print_button.place(x=200, y=325)

# save button
save_button = tk.Button(mainWindow, text="Save", padx=20, pady=0, command=save_as)
save_button.place(x=300, y=325)

# exit button
exit_button = tk.Button(mainWindow, text="Exit", padx=20, pady=0, command=quit_program)
exit_button.place(x=400, y=325)

# run the program
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

[image: GUI]

Comment: Instead of using `return(url)` try using `outputTextbox.insert("end", url)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `printOut` function is not working because after replacing the URL you are not inserting it in the `outputTextbox`. After all conditions in `printout` function, you should replace `return url` code from this.

```
outputTextbox.insert(1.0, url)
```

Comment: It's better to use `"1.0"` instead of `1.0`

Comment: @TheLizzard why? can you please explain me

Comment: Do you know how `tk.Text` indices work? It is better to give it as a string otherwise some indices will clash like `1.10` will be converted to `"1.1"` in the tcl world. It is a major simplification.

Comment: @TheLizzard btw isn't the `"1.0"` the end already? if so might as well just use `"end"`, no?

Comment: @Matiiss True `"end"` would be equivalent to `"1.0"`. But I was trying to teach EriqCodes that `tk.Text` indices should be strings instead of floats

Comment: @EriqCodes thank you for this! That worked great, I also added a "\n" at the end to newline my inputs  `outputTextbox.insert("1.0", url, "\n")`

Comment: @TheLizzard Ok,  I understood why I should use strings.